# Twitter API: How to get follower's liked content in home_timeline

Tags: twitter

I am attempting to retrieve the home timeline of an authenticated user using the `statuses/home_timeline` API [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline), and I noticed that the returned results only **show content "posted" and "retweeted"** by the user's followers but **nothing "liked" by the user's followers**.

Is there an API that provides that or am I missing out something?

Answer (score 0):

The home timeline API does not support providing liked Tweets, it will only show Tweets posted or Retweeted by people followed by the user. The addition of occasional likes into the home timeline in the app was introduced after the home timeline API was released (about 6 years later, in fact), and the API itself never had those changes made.